# ¿Como llamar una función de un componente desde otro componente?

Tags: reactjs

Tengo el siguiente problema, necesito llamar una función desde un componente al otro.

Tengo el componente X donde se verifica cuando el usuario hace scroll hasta el final del sitio, cuando esto pasa puedes hacer una acción sea un alert, un setState o lo que sea.

```
  container.onscroll = function () {
  let height = this.clientHeight;
  let scrollHeight = this.scrollHeight;
  let scrollTop = this.scrollTop;

  if (height + scrollTop === scrollHeight) {
     _this.setState({ display: 'loader'});
      funcionupdate() <--
     setTimeout(function(){  _this.setState({ display: 'hidden'}); }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Por otro lado el componente Y, en el cual hay una función `update()`.

Como puedo ejecutar la función `update()` del componente `Y` desde el componente `X`?

Comment: No creo que se pueda si no comparten el DOM. Lo que puedes hacer es redireccionar al componente Y, ejecutar su función en el ready u onload y ya que termine redireccionar nuevamente al componente X.

Comment: No me serviria esa opcion, ya que esto se debe hacer sin recargar el sitio en ningun momento

Comment: Qué hace el update() del componente Y?

Comment: Aun no la he creado pero debera actualizar el contenido del componente

Comment: Digamos volver a hacer fetch y mostrar el contenido actualizado

Comment: ¿El componente X y el componente Y son hermanos o padre e hijo?

Comment: Son hermanos guz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo por [`Context`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html), para lo cual el contenedor padre debe contener la función a ejecutar cuando el scroll llega hacia abajo. En caso de comunicar componentes que ni siquiera son hermanos, sería muy complejo de este modo. La mejor opción para mantener las cosas simples es implementar en la aplicación el patrón de diseño Observer. De esta manera puedes establecer comunicación entre cualquier grupo de componentes (no solo dos). Puedes usar librerías para esto como [Postal.js](https://github.com/postaljs/postal.js), [PubSub.js](https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS), [MicroEvent.js](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/microevent.js) o [EventEmitter2](https://github.com/asyncly/EventEmitter2).

**Ejemplo**

```js
class Sidebar extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      message: ''
    };
    this.channel = null;
  }
  
  render () {
    return (
      <aside className="sidebar">
        { this.state.message }
      </aside>
    );
  }
  
  componentDidMount () {
    this.channel = postal.channel();
    this.channel.subscribe('scroll.end', (data) => {
      console.info('Received data:', data);
      this.onScrollContentEnd();
    });
  }
  
  onScrollContentEnd () {
    // hacer algo
    this.setState({
      message: 'Scroll End'
    });
  }
}

class Content extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.channel = null;
  }
  
  render () {
    return (
      <article className="content" onScroll={this.onscroll.bind(this)}>
        <div id="big"></div>
      </article>
    );
  }
  
  componentDidMount () {
    this.channel = postal.channel();
  }
  
  onscroll (e) {
    let el = e.target;
    let height = el.clientHeight;
    let scrollHeight = el.scrollHeight;
    let scrollTop = el.scrollTop;

    if (height + scrollTop === scrollHeight) {
      // puedes enviar datos opcionales ;)
      this.channel.publish('scroll.end', {
        someData: 'xyz123'
      });
    }
  }
}

class Container extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <section ref="el" className="container">
        <Sidebar/>
        <Content/>
      </section>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Container/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: #f39c12;
  color: #fff;
  flex: 0 0 240px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Ubuntu';
  line-height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

#big {
  height: 1200px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/postal.js/2.0.5/postal.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

---

**Nota:** el ejemplo usa la librería [Postal.js](https://github.com/postaljs/postal.js) que a su vez depende de [lodash](https://lodash.com/).